# Relative paths for ItemGroup items in msbuild .targets files

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a .dll and a .targets file in the same directory. Inside of that .targets file I would like to add the .dll to an ItemGroup item. However if I just add it similar to this:

```
<Example Include="Example.dll" />
```

The path to Example.dll appears to be resolving as relative to the .csproj that is including the .targets file. How can I add items to an ItemGroup in a .targets file with a relative path like this?

For example suppose I have:

```
C:\lib\Example.dll
C:\lib\Example.targets
C:\src\Example.csproj
```

When including the Example.dll from inside the .targets file the full path resolves to `C:\src\Example.dll` which is wrong, what I want is `C:\lib\Example.dll`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the .targets file, use this,

```
<Example Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Example.dll" />
```

...that reserved property will resolve to the directory in which the .targets file resides, not the project file importing the .targets file, which is the default for relative path resolution.